# PHP exec() giving error on GCE

Tags: php, shell, google-compute-engine

I have a PHP script where i am running a shell script to get list of GCE in my project.

```
$output = shell_exec("sudo gcloud compute instances list");
```

The command was running fine till yesterday. Today i tried to run this command and it stopped showing any output.

I tried adding 2>&1 and it shows the following error:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I have not made any changes in the system. Can someone please tell me where to start looking for the problem?

I have search on StackOverflow but did not find anything useful. Even if i run sudo whoami, it gives the same error.

Comment: `sudo` wants password. Has `sudo` been asking password before? Should it be asking password?

Comment: @MarkusLaire no it never asked for password before.

Comment: By default `sudo` will ask for a password, see https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.17/sudoers.man.html

Comment: also i am running it on GCE, so there is no root password provided. when i run the sudo command from terminal, then also it never asks for a password

Comment: It's not the root password, its the password of the user trying to run `sudo`.  Check out `sudoers` to configure no password in `sudo.conf`.

Comment: i will check sudo.conf and will let you know. but when i run sudo command from terminal, then also it never asks for a password